# How do I remove duplicated rows in an H2O.Frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, h2o

I need to remove duplicated rows in an `H2O.Frame` object.

With a `data.frame` `df` in R I would use

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

What is the equivalent in H2O? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There currently isn't a method to drop duplicate rows but jira tickets have been created for [Python](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3292) and [R](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3293)

If however you have some sort of identifier like an id column with duplicated rows you might be able to use h2o's `h2o.group_by` method to help with the removal process.